# Pentaho7 CE net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: tomcat, pentaho

I'm using `pentaho-server-ce-7.1.0.0-12`. Server is running behind `Nginx`, which is configured to terminate SSL. Relevant config snippets:

*Nginx*:

```
  location / {
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  }
```

*tomcat/conf/server.xml*:

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000" secure="true" proxyPort="443" scheme="https"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

*pentaho-solutions/system/server.properties*:

```
fully-qualified-server-url=https://pentaho.example.com/pentaho/
```

When I connect with my browser I'm getting the following error in the console:

```
https://pentaho.example.comhttps//pentaho.example.com/pentaho/api/mantle/isAuthenticated net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED 9914D6E890675FEA759846BEC2F6A9E9.cache.html:4558
```

Note the URL: `https://pentaho.example.comhttps//pentaho.example.com/pentaho/...`

Obviously this is **invalid** `DNS`, but I'm not sure why or where `Pentaho7` has crafted url in a such way. Same configuration worked fine with `Pentaho6`. Any ideas?